# How to install React Js with CodeIgniter..?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, codeigniter, reactjs

Possible duplicates:

- [Codeigniter and React.JS setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504206/codeigniter-and-react-js-setup)
- [React.JS setup with Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972265/react-js-setup-with-codeigniter)
- [how to implement react js in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945737/how-to-implement-react-js-in-codeigniter)
- [ReactJS not rendering php codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384814/reactjs-not-rendering-php-codeigniter)

Above given links are not working properly.

I followed the procedure to install React Js using [facebook-create-app](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html) in windows, it works perfectly. But i need to work **React Js** with in
**CodeIgniter**. How to install and run it..?

Answer (score 1):

**CodeIgniter with React**

CodeIgniter code is little bit changed to accommodate theming structure. Also there are significant changes done and some are in progress, to support rendering using React JS.

The changes are done in such a way, which put this repository in the state, in which it can be used in multiple ways, the default being rendering the views using React and it supports the default CodeIgniter views also.

Here you can find much more infos : https://github.com/kala725/CodeIgniter-with-React

**Second one**

Another example which I tried two years ago I think : https://github.com/Jineshfrancisco/React_Vue_Frontend_Scaffolding

1. download the repository from github
2. extract into your codeigniter project folder
3. link css and js files  in public folder into your view file
4. edit the package.json file and other (watch the Video)
5. run the command "npm run watch"   or "npm run prod"

video tutorial explains almost all you need on youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ba6y3r69VE

**Codeigniter + Reactjs – Integration**

See this tutorial is well for step by step https://www.tutofox.com/react/codeigniter-reactjs-integracion/

Comment: The first one is actually what I want to do . Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is installation guide https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html it’s to long to add in question, Would you please accept answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using React+ CodeIgniter for a small personal project I am working on currently. React is wonderful for creating dynamic, interactive front-ends. PHP developers are available in plenty to develop the REST backend, with the added advantage of very cheap, shared hosting. Some simple "formsy" admin pages are also done in CodeIgniter, making my bundle size smaller and maybe some added security.

You need to first build the create-react-app project using

```
npm run build
```

When it finishes, you will find the 'index.html' and other required files inside the "project_folder/build" folder. Copy everything into the Apache htdocs folder. I put the codeigniter files into "htdocs/api" folder. You will need to do some redirects with '.htaccess'.

Comment: Not very useful answer, maybe you should explain more of your last two sentences. That's where your real answer starts.